# How to union one column only from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am finding it hard to frame the question so I will show what I am trying to do.

```
Table1 (ID, Name, Score)  
1 Jane  10  
2 Jack  15  
3 Jill  12  
4 Jane  10  


Table2 (ID, Name, Score)  
1 John  11  
2 Jill  14  
3 Jack  16  
4 Jake  15
```

The result I would like is

```
Result (Name, Table1.Score, Table2.Score)  
Jane 20   NULL
Jack 15   16
Jill 12   14
John NULL 11
Jake NULL 15
```

Can name become the primary key? Note that Jane occurs twice in table 1(could occur in table 2 as well) and I want to sum the score and make the name unique in that given table.

Comment: If you make name unique, what do you do about people with the same name?

Comment: Its not my database and it was a poor design, so I added a 'users' table to list all names. Still there if there are two same names they have to use a number/initial to make it unique. I have some 30+ tables and it would be a disaster to solve this problem without a table for names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `UNION` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT T.Name, Sum(T.Score), Sum(T2.Score) Score2
FROM (SELECT Name, SUM(Score) score FROM Table1 GROUP BY Name)  t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name, SUM(Score) score FROM Table2  GROUP BY Name) t2
ON t.Name = t2.Name
GROUP BY T.Name
UNION   
SELECT T.Name, Sum(T2.Score), Sum(T.Score) Score2
FROM (SELECT Name, SUM(Score) score FROM Table2 GROUP BY Name)  t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name, SUM(Score) score FROM Table1  GROUP BY Name) t2
ON t.Name = t2.Name
GROUP BY T.Name
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08c48/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 select  t1.name , sum(t1.score) as score1 ,sum(t2.score2) as score2 from Table1 as t1
 left JOIN 
 (select  name , score as score2 from Table2 )t2 
 on t1.name = t2.name 
 group by name

 union all

 select  t2.name , sum(t1.score1) as score1, sum(t2.score) as score2  from Table2 as t2
 left JOIN 
 (select  name , score as score1 from Table1 )t1 
 on t2.name = t1.name 
 where score1 is  null

 group by name
 ---- if you want use the order add this "order by name" here in the end
```

and this will output :

```
  NAME |    SCORE1  |SCORE2
  Jack |     15     | 16
  Jane |     20     |(null)
  Jill |     12     | 14
  Jake |    (null)  | 15
  John |    (null)  | 11
```

[**HERE SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64eb3/102)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if MySQL had `full outer join`, you would use that.  Here is an alternative method:

```
select id, name, MAX(score1) as score1, MAX(score2) as score2
from ((select  id, name, score as score1, NULL as score2
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select  id, name, null as score1, score as score2
       from table1
      )
     ) t
group by id, name
```

The idea is to get all information needed from each table, with the score in different columns, by using the `union all` and splitting the score into two separate columns.

The final `group by` brings them together with one row per id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
name = Table1.name, 
sum(Table1.score) as score1,
sum(Table2.Score) as score2
from Table1
full outer join
Table2 
ON 
Table2.name = Table1.name
where Table1.name is not null
group by table1.name

UNION

select 
name = Table2.name, 
sum(Table1.score) as score1,
sum(Table2.Score) as score2
from Table1
full outer join
Table2 
ON 
Table2.name = Table1.name
where Table2.name is not null
group by table2.name

order by score1 desc, score2
```